# Hybris HAC - How to change background color based on environment?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have several servers.
Hybris is installed on each one and I would like to be able to choose the background color of the HAC based on the environment in which I am.

Example:

- Development environment = BLUE color
- Test environment = GREEN color
- Production environment = RED color

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you have to modify some lines in the `hybris\bin\platform\ext\hac\web\webroot\static\css\style.css` file.

You should:

- find the `body.logincontainer` selector and comment out lines:

  ```
  background-color: #162c5e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1d346b, #162c5f) #162c5e;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1d346b, #162c5f) #162c5e;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1d346b, #162c5f) #162c5e;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#1d346b), to(#162c5f) ) #162c5e;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1d346b, #162c5f) #162c5e;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #1d346b, #162c5f) #162c5e;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#1d346b, endColorstr=#162c5f);               
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#1d346b, endColorstr#162c5f);
  ```
- add to the `body.logincontainer` the following line:

  ```
  background-color: red;
  ```
- find the `body` selector and comment out line:

  ```
  background: url("../img/bodyBG.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #4B5367;
  ```
- add to the `body` selector the following line:

  ```
  background-color: red;
  ```

Then HAC will look as follow:

[image: HAC login]
[image: HAC application]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this automatically, for every developer installing the project or/and every deployment on each environment :

1. In the folder : `deployment/cmdb` , in the `application.properties` files, you have to add this for your different environment:

   - *DEV environment* : no need to changes this environment, just use the default templates
   - *TEST environment* : `#custom hac/backoffice css`

     > xxx.backoffice.extracss=body {background: #006600 none !important;}
     >   xxx.hac.extracss=body {background: #006600 none !important;}
   - *PROD environment :* `#custom hac/backoffice css`

     > xxx.backoffice.extracss=body {background: #660000 none !important;}
     >   xxx.hac.extracss=body {background: #660000 none !important;}

     2. In the `src/hybris/bin/custom/xxx/xxxcore/buildcallbacks.xml`, go to the balise `<macrodef name="xxx_before_build">` and add:

        > ```
        >   <if>
        >     <isset property="xxx.backoffice.extracss"/>
        >     <then>
        >       <echo message="Customizing hmc css with ${xxx.backoffice.extracss}"/>
        >       <echo file="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/xxx/xxxcore/hmc/jsp/ext/xxxcore/css/xxxcore.css">${xxx.backoffice.extracss}</echo>
        >     </then>
        >     <else>
        >       <echo file="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/xxx/xxxcore/hmc/jsp/ext/xxxcore/css/xxxcore.css"/>
        >     </else>
        >   </if>
        >   <if>
        >     <isset property="xxx.hac.extracss"/>
        >     <then>
        >       <echo message="Customizing hac css with ${xxx.hac.extracss}"/>
        >       <echo file="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform/ext/hac/web/webroot/static/css/xxxcore.css">${xxx.hac.extracss}</echo>
        >     </then>
        >     <else>
        >       <echo file="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform/ext/hac/web/webroot/static/css/xxxcore.css"/>
        >     </else>
        >   </if>
        > ```
     3. In the `src/hybris/bin/ext-platform-optional/hmc/web/webroot/css/hmc.css` add :

        > /*=== Start Extension:xxxcore File:xxxcore.css===*/
        >
        > `body {background: #333333 none !important;}`
2. In the `platform/ext/hac/web/webroot/static/css/style.css` add :

   > @IMPORT url("xxxcore.css");
3. In `src/hybris/config/customize/platform/ext/hac/web/webroot/static/css/style.css` add :

   > @IMPORT url("xxxcore.css");

NOTE : **DONT FORGET TO REPLACE** xxx by your name extension !

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use this extension: https://github.com/sap-commerce-tools/environment-ribbon

It's not changing page theme but still allows to easily distinguish between environments by adding a ribbon in the corner of the page.

The advantage is that it also works for Backoffice.